# Get effected rows in transaction in asp.net

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

I am using SQL trasaction in .net code .
I need rows effected after transaction.
I have follwing code

Dim result2 As Integer = New SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection,    transaction).ExecuteNonQuery()

transaction.Commit()

But  result2  variable returns always zero even if rows are effected .

can any one please provide me solution ?

Comment: What is sql.ToString() value ?

Comment: Show your sql statement

Comment: I was missing to close connection  before Exit Sub                                 If result2 = 0 Then
               show error pop up 
                connection.Close()
                Exit Sub   , Here i missed close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ExecuteNonQuery()` which use only when our query will not return any value. So it will always give you 0. You need to use `ExecuteScalar()` and create a stored procedure in which you can return no of affected rows.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() will return rows effected .